# Square symbol with a number inside

Tags: qgis, symbology

How do I create a symbol on qgis that has a number assigned to it? I am trying to make a square symbol with a number inside. everytime I place the marker I would like it to ask me what the number is everytime so I can place specific number symbols in different areas on my map. Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: I created a new layer with a symbol and added a new field called type. then on the label tab I tied it to that type field but nothing shows up when I try to plot it.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually do this through symbology rather than a mixed symbology-label style as you suggest in your comment above.

1. Make sure the field that contains the relevant number you want
   displayed is a **string** type, it won't work otherwise.
2. Symbolise your point layer with your square background
3. Add a new symbol layer above the square - set the symbology type to "Font Marker"

[image]

4. Rather than setting a particular font marker, set the data defined override to equal the field that contains your marker - format as required

[image]

To get it to ask you what the number is each time you digitise a feature you need to turn on the attribute form popup for your layer. You can do this through Properties -> Fields. Then when you're editing the layer, every time you digitise a new point it will produce an input box to allow you to edit the field and will automatically display this on the map.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A slight modification to this setup can place your text beside a SVG symbol by tweaking the Font Marker Offset to not cover it with text or a number.